# How to automatically fill a one2many field values to another one2many field in odoo

Tags: python, odoo-8

I have two one2many field which is reffering to a single model, existing in different models.

ie,

```
    class modelA(models.Model):
       _name = 'modela'

       fila = fields.One2many('main','refa')

   class moddelB(models.Model):
      _name = 'modelb'

      filb = fields.One2many('main','refb')


   class main(models.Model):
     _name = 'main'

     name = fields.Char('Name')
     date = fields.Date('Date')
     refa = fields.Many2one('modela')
     refb = fields.Many2one('modelb')
```

I will create records in **modela**. In this model there is a button is there. On clicking on that button i need to copy all values of fila field to filb field of  **modelb** . How can i do that.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [One2many values filling](http://odoo-development.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/py/x2many.html#x2many-values-filling)

**XML code**

```
<button name="copy2b" type="object" string="COPY"/>
```

**Python code**:

```
@api.multi
def copy2b(self):
    for record in self:
        filb_values = [(0, 0, {'name': line.name, 'date': line.date}) for line in record.fila]
        vals = {'filb': filb_values}
        # Just pass these values to `create` or `write` method to save them on `modelb`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for record in ids:
    field_vals=[(0,0,{'product_name':line.product_id.name,'qty':line.quantity}) for line in record.invoice_line_ids]
    vals={'inv_products':field_vals}

    my_invoices=self.env["cron.invoice"].search([])
    my_invoices.write(vals)
```

worked for me.
here, i am getting products from invoice_line_ids field of account.invoice model.
"for record in ids"
here ids is correspond invoice.
then i am loop through invoice using "record" thus i can access invoice_line_ids one2many field of invoice.
"inv_products" is my another one2many field in same model which is "cron.invoice".
before wrote into same model i had use create method for create some fields. then i can use search() method. which will return all crated records.